# What's the difference StreamingResponse or EventSourceResponse?

Tags: python, streaming, fastapi, starlette

I'm looking to stream back server side events generated by LLM.
I noticed that LiteLLM and LangChain use the built in StreamingResponse.
I also came across https://github.com/sysid/sse-starlette ServerSideEvent

Has anyone experimented with both?
Differences and advantages / disadvantages to using one or the other?
I'm curious what's your input / suggestion.

Comment: StreamingResponse is a general response that handles a streaming source, while EventSourceResponse is a specific response that implements the server side event protocol.

Comment: Mats, that is very obvious, I also looked at the source code. EventSourceResponse is a custom developed and doesn't inherit from StreamingResponse. looks likeEventSourceRespose has a few issue / limitations with async, I'm not 100% sure.

I'm looking for a bit more in depth explanation, than the obvious answer.
So far I'm leaning towards using StreamingResponse.

Comment: It was the title of your question after all, so I left it as a comment to clarify. Feel free to flag it if you believe it's unnecessary.

Comment: StreamingResponse is streaming one response, whereas SSE can send multiple events (responses). SSE is used when you need somewhat of websocket messaging but only from server side. StreamingResponse is used when you either have a huge data (streaming a file) or you are streaming another stream (proxying a content)